# Hash function that returns the same hash for a sum even if different terms lead to the same sum

Tags: hash, sum, hashcode, hash-function

let's say I have:

```
n = 14
```

`n` is the result of the following sums of integers:

```
[5, 2, 7] -> 5 + 2 + 7 = 14 = n
[3, 4, 5, 2] -> 3 + 4 + 5 + 2 = 14 = n
[1, 13] -> 1 + 13 = 14 = n
[13, 1] -> 13 + 1 = 14 = n
[4, 3, 5, 2] -> 4 + 3 + 5 + 2 = 14 = n
...
```

I would need a hash function `h` so that:

```
h([5, 2, 7]) = h([3, 4, 5, 2]) = h([1, 13]) = h([13, 1]) = h([4, 3, 5, 2]) = h(...)
```

I.e. it doesn't matter the order of the integer terms and as long as their integer sum is the same, their hash should also the same.

I need to do this without computing the sum `n`, because the terms as well as `n` can be very high and easily overflow (they don't fit the bits of an `int`), that's why I am asking this question.

Are you aware or maybe do you have an insight on how I can implement such a hash function?
Given a list/sequence of integers, this hash function must return the same hash if the sum of the integers would be the same, but without computing the sum.

Thank you for your attention.

EDIT: I elaborated on @derpirscher's answer and modified his function a bit further as I had collisions on multiples of `BIG_PRIME` (this example is in JavaScript):

```js
function hash(seq) {
  const BIG_PRIME = 999999999989;
  const MAX_SAFE_INTEGER_DIV_2_FLOOR = Math.floor(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER / 2);
  let h = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < seq.length; i++) {
    let value = seq[i];
    if (h > MAX_SAFE_INTEGER_DIV_2_FLOOR) {
      h = h % BIG_PRIME;
    }
    if (value > MAX_SAFE_INTEGER_DIV_2_FLOOR) {
      value = value % BIG_PRIME;
    }
    h += value;
  }
  return h;
}
```

My question now would be: what do you think about this function? Are there some edge cases I didn't take into account?

Thank you.

EDIT 2:

Using the above function `hash([1,2]);` and `hash([4504 * BIG_PRIME +1, 4504 * BIG_PRIME + 2])` will collide as mentioned by @derpirscher.

Here is another modified of version of the above function, which computes the modulo `% BIG_PRIME` only to one of the two terms if either of the two are greater than `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER_DIV_2_FLOOR`:

```js
function hash(seq) {
  const BIG_PRIME = 999999999989;
  const MAX_SAFE_INTEGER_DIV_2_FLOOR = Math.floor(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER / 2);
  let h = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < seq.length; i++) {
    let value = seq[i];
    if (
      h > MAX_SAFE_INTEGER_DIV_2_FLOOR &&
      value > MAX_SAFE_INTEGER_DIV_2_FLOOR
    ) {
      if (h > MAX_SAFE_INTEGER_DIV_2_FLOOR) {
        h = h % BIG_PRIME;
      } else if (value > MAX_SAFE_INTEGER_DIV_2_FLOOR) {
        value = value % BIG_PRIME;
      }
    }
    h += value;
  }
  return h;
}
```

I think this version lowers the number of collisions a bit further.

What do you think? Thank you.

EDIT 3:

Even though I tried to elaborate on @derpirscher's answer, his implementation of `hash` is the correct one and the one to use.

Use his version if you need such an hash function.

Comment: I'd say that computing the sum ist the cheapest way to calculate a hash value. And if you'd get overflows when doing additions, you'll get overflows with most other operations as well. The logical operations that won't overflow probably also won't satisfy the requirement. BTW always issuing 37 as a hash value, regardless the input, would satisfy your requirement.

Comment: Acutually, there is no difference at all to my approach. You are just using a bigger modulus, because the the range of javascript's `number` is bigger than c# `int` (which I took as basis for my answer). You will get the inevitable collisions (but at bigger values), once the elements (or the sum) in your sequence get bigger than `MAX_SAVE_INTEGER_DIV_2_FLOOR`.  Try `hash([1,2]);` and `hash([4504*BIG_PRIME +1, 4504*BIG_PRIME +2])` they both will return `3`.

Comment: Furthermore, I'd suggest to use a value for `BIG_PRIME` that is as near as possible to `MAX_SAVE_INTEGER_DIV_2_FLOOR` because that will reduce the number of collisions dramatically.

Comment: And there is literally no difference between `x = x % N` and `if (x > N) x = x % N` because any reasonable implementation of `%` will do this conditional check anyways, and if `x < N` just return `x` without further calculations.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, @derpirscher. In my case `N = BIG_PRIME = 999999999989`, but the test checks against a different number, `Y = MAX_SAFE_INTEGER_DIV_2_FLOOR`, so it's `if (x > Y) x = x % N` in my case.

Comment: `Try hash([1,2]); and hash([4504*BIG_PRIME +1, 4504*BIG_PRIME +2]) they both will return 3.` Yeah, they collide.

Comment: What if I compute the modulo `value % BIG_PRIME`  only to one of the two terms of the sum `h + value`? This way `hash([1,2]);` and `hash([4504*BIG_PRIME +1, 4504*BIG_PRIME +2])` don't collide. Please, check my EDIT 2, thank you!

Comment: It doesn't matter. Once you use a modulo operation, you get collisions. Fact. Maybe for different inputs, but they are inevitable. Btw. With your latest approach you may produce overflows. Assume `h == 20` and `value == Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - 1`. Then you are computing `h = 20 + value` which will result `h` to be `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 19` ...

Comment: BTW, your `else if` branch will never be executed, because once you enter the body of the outer `if` the condition of the inner `if` is always `true` ...

Comment: You are right, I am going back to the implementation of `hash` in your answer, as it is the correct one. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could calculate the sum modulo some big prime. If you want to stay within the range of `int`, you need to know what the maximum integer is, in the language you are using. Then select a `BIG_PRIME` that's just below `maxint / 2`

Assuming an `int` to be 4 bytes, `maxint = 2147483647` thus the biggest prime `< maxint/2` would be `1073741789`;

```
int hash(int[] seq) {
  BIG_PRIME = 1073741789;
  int h = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < seq.Length; i++) {
    h = (h + seq[i] % BIG_PRIME) % BIG_PRIME;
  }
  return h;
}
```

As at every step both summands will always be below `maxint/2` you won't get any overflows.

**Edit**

From a mathematical point of view, the following property which may be important for your use case holds:

```
(a + b + c + ...) % N  == (a % N + b % N + c % N + ...) % N
```

But yeah, of course, as in every hash function you will have collisions. You can't have a hash function without collisions, because the size of the domain of the hash function (ie the number of possible input values) is generally much bigger than the the size of the codomain (ie the number of possible output values).

For your example the size of the domain is (in principle) infinite, as you can have any count of numbers from 1 to 2000000000 in your sequence. But your codomain is just ~2000000000 elements (ie the range of int)

Comment: I like this idea, thank you!

Comment: How does this algorithm work when all values of `seq` are `> BIG_PRIME`? It basically sums the remainders of the division by `BIG_PRIME`, e.g. `seq = [BIG_PRIME + 2, BIG_PRIME + 7, BIG_PRIME + 3]` so I guess that as long as the sum of these remainders is the same, two sequences will have the same hash, e.g. `hash([BIG_PRIME + 2, BIG_PRIME + 7, BIG_PRIME + 3]) = hash([BIG_PRIME + 12]) = hash([BIG_PRIME + 7, BIG_PRIME + 5])`. But how can I make `hash([7, 5])` produce a different hash? Thank you!

Comment: To generalize, for any multiple `n : {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...}` of `BIG_PRIME`, `hash([n * BIG_PRIME + 2, n * BIG_PRIME + 7, n * BIG_PRIME + 3])` will lead to the same hash as `hash([2, 7, 3])`, but I would like sequence `[2, 7, 3]` to have a different hash than e.g. `hash([BIG_PRIME + 2, BIG_PRIME + 7, BIG_PRIME + 3])` or `hash([2 * BIG_PRIME + 2, 2 * BIG_PRIME + 7, 2 * BIG_PRIME + 3])` or `hash([3 * BIG_PRIME + 2, 3 * BIG_PRIME + 7, 3 * BIG_PRIME + 3])` and so on...

Comment: That's not possible with this approach. For that you'll need something else. But that, will as any other hash function also have collisions ..

Comment: What do you think about my EDIT? It seems to work well

Comment: @tonix Actually, there is no difference at all to my approach. You are just using a bigger datatype and therefore pushing the limit where you get collions a bit higher ...

Comment: Using modulo doesn't lead to a great distribution of hash values unless the original values already have great distribution which is bad if the hash function is used for a hash map

Comment: @JimmyT. you are right. But that wasn't the point of the question ...

Comment: I've realized that your mathematical proof doesn't equal the code where you always use modulo on partial sums, making the order relevant.
Maybe I did something wrong but I found two cases with the same numbers (so same sum) but in different order:
`hash([1073741789,1073741789,73741789,2073741790]) = 1073741790`
`hash([1073741789,73741789,2073741790,1073741789]) = 1`

Comment: @JimmyT. you are right. I forgot a final `% BIG_PRIME` ...